# Execute unit tests serially (rather than in parallel)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit.net

I am attempting to unit test a WCF host management engine that I have written. The engine basically creates ServiceHost instances on the fly based on configuration. This allows us to dynamically reconfigure which services are available without having to bring all of them down and restart them whenever a new service is added or an old one is removed.

I have run into a difficulty in unit testing this host management engine, however, due to the way ServiceHost works. If a ServiceHost has already been created, opened, and not yet closed for a particular endpoint, another ServiceHost for the same endpoint can not be created, resulting in an exception. Because of the fact that modern unit testing platforms parallelize their test execution, I have no effective way to unit test this piece of code.

I have used xUnit.NET, hoping that because of its extensibility, I could find a way to force it to run the tests serially. However, I have not had any luck. I am hoping that someone here on SO has encountered a similar issue and knows how to get unit tests to run serially.

NOTE: [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) is a WCF class, written by Microsoft. I don't have the ability to change its behavior. Hosting each service endpoint only once is also the proper behavior...however, it is not particularly conducive to unit testing.

Comment: Wouldn't this particular behavior of ServiceHost be something you might want to address?

Comment: ServiceHost is written by Microsoft. I have no control over it. And technically speaking, it is valid behavior...you should never have more than one ServiceHost per endpoint.

Comment: I had similar issue trying to run multiple `TestServer` in docker. So I had to serialise the integration tests.

Answer (score 332):

Each test class is a unique test collection and tests under it will run in sequence, so if you put all of your tests in same collection then it will run sequentially.

In xUnit you can make following changes to achieve this:

**Following will run in parallel:**

```
namespace IntegrationTests
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test1 called");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test2 called");
        }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test3 called");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test4()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test4 called");
        }
    }
}
```

**To make it sequential you just need to put both the test classes under same collection:**

```
namespace IntegrationTests
{
    [Collection("Sequential")]
    public class Class1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test1 called");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test2 called");
        }
    }

    [Collection("Sequential")]
    public class Class2
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test3 called");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test4()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test4 called");
        }
    }
}
```

For more info you can refer to [this link](https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html)

Comment: Underappreciated answer, I think. Seems to work and I like the granularity, as I have parallelizable and nonparallelizable tests in one assembly.

Comment: This is the correct way to do this, ref Xunit documentation.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because typically some tests can be run in parallel (in my case all unit tests), but some fail randomly when run in parallel (in my case those using in-memory web client / server), so one is able to optimize test running if one wishes so.

Comment: This did not work for me in a .net core project where I perform integration tests with a sqlite database. The tests were still executed in parallel. The accepted answer did work though.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Needed to do this as I have Acceptance Tests in different classes that both inherit from the same TestBase and the concurrency wasn't playing nice with EF Core.

Comment: In my case the parallel execution in the db context, caused some issues between some shared data, this solved my problem

Answer (score 155):

*Preface: All good unit tests should be 100% isolated. Using shared state (e.g. depending on a `static` property that is modified by each test) is regarded as bad practice.*

I encountered exactly the same issue because my system uses a static service locator (which is less than ideal).

By default xUnit 2.x runs all tests in parallel. This can be modified per-assembly by defining the `CollectionBehavior` in your AssemblyInfo.cs in your test project.

For per-assembly separation use:

```
using Xunit;
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(CollectionBehavior.CollectionPerAssembly)]
```

or for no parallelization at all use:

```
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
```

The latter is probably the one you want. More information about parallelisation and configuration can be found on the [xUnit documentation](https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html).

Comment: For me, there were shared resources between methods within each class. Running a test from one class, then one from another, would break tests from both. I was able to resolve by using `[assembly: CollectionBehavior(CollectionBehavior.CollectionPerClass, DisableTestParallelization = true)]`. Thanks to you, @Squiggle, I can run all my tests and go take a coffee! :)

Comment: The answer from Abhinav Saxena is more granular for .NET Core.

Comment: This works for me in .NET Core as well.

Answer (score 144):

For .NET Core projects, create `xunit.runner.json` with:

```
{
  "parallelizeAssembly": false,
  "parallelizeTestCollections": false
}
```

Also, your `csproj` should contain

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="xunit.runner.json"> 
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

For old .Net Core projects, your `project.json` should contain

```
"buildOptions": {
  "copyToOutput": {
    "include": [ "xunit.runner.json" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume the latest csproj dotnet core equivalent would be `<ItemGroup><None Include="xunit.runner.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" /></ItemGroup>` or similar?

Comment: This worked for me in csproj: `<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="xunit.runner.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: Does disabling parallelization work with xUnit Theories?

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, I tried running like `dotnet test --no-build -c Release -- xunit.parallelizeTestCollections=false` but it did not work for me.

Comment: Work it only adding the new config. Is not necesary changed anything at csproj

Answer (score 38):

For .NET Core projects, you can configure xUnit with an `xunit.runner.json` file, as documented at https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files.

The setting you need to change to stop parallel test execution is `parallelizeTestCollections`, which defaults to `true`:

> Set this to `true` if the assembly is willing to run tests inside this assembly in parallel against each other. ... Set this to `false` to disable all parallelization within this test assembly.

> *JSON schema type: **boolean***
> *Default value: `true`*

So a minimal `xunit.runner.json` for this purpose looks like

```
{
    "parallelizeTestCollections": false
}
```

As noted in the docs, remember to include this file in your build, either by:

- Setting *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy if newer* in the file's *Properties* in Visual Studio, or
- Adding

  ```
    <Content Include=".\xunit.runner.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  ```

  to your `.csproj` file, or
- Adding

  ```
    "buildOptions": {
      "copyToOutput": {
        "include": [ "xunit.runner.json" ]
      }
    }
  ```

  to your `project.json` file

depending upon your project type.

Finally, *in addition* to the above, if you're using Visual Studio then make sure that you haven't accidentally clicked the *Run Tests In Parallel* button, which will cause tests to run in parallel even if you've turned off parallelisation in `xunit.runner.json`. Microsoft's UI designers have cunningly made this button unlabelled, hard to notice, and about a centimetre away from the *"Run All"* button in Test Explorer, just to maximise the chance that you'll hit it by mistake and have no idea why your tests are suddenly failing:

[image: Screenshot with the button circled]

Comment: @JohnZabroski I don't understand your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22900971). What does ReSharper have to do with anything? I think I probably had it installed when I wrote the answer above, but isn't everything here independent of whether you're using it or not? What does the [page you link to in the edit](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/08/23/new-features-in-resharper-6-unit-test-runner/) have to do with specifying an `xunit.runner.json` file? And what does specifying an `xunit.runner.json` have to do with making tests run serially?

Comment: I'm trying to get my tests to run serially, and initially thought the issue was related to ReSharper (since ReSharper does NOT have the "Run Tests in Parallel" button like the Visual Studio Test Explorer does).  However, it seems when I use [Theory], my tests are not isolated.  This is strange, because everything I read suggests a Class is the smallest parallelizable unit.

Answer (score 27):

This is old question but I wanted to write a solution to people searching newly like me :)

**Note:** I use this method in Dot Net Core WebUI integration tests with xunit version 2.4.1.

Create an empty class named NonParallelCollectionDefinitionClass and then give CollectionDefinition attribute to this class as below. (The important part is DisableParallelization = true setting.)

```
using Xunit;

namespace WebUI.IntegrationTests.Common
{
    [CollectionDefinition("Non-Parallel Collection", DisableParallelization = true)]
    public class NonParallelCollectionDefinitionClass
    {
    }
}
```

After then add Collection attribute to the class which you don't want it to run in parallel as below. (The important part is name of collection. It must be same with name used in CollectionDefinition)

```
namespace WebUI.IntegrationTests.Controllers.Users
{
    [Collection("Non-Parallel Collection")]
    public class ChangePassword : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    ...
```

When we do this, firstly other parallel tests run. After that the other tests which has  Collection("Non-Parallel Collection") attribute run.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me in .net core to run a tests in the same collection sequentially, and parallel with other tests in the same assembly

Answer (score 6):

I don't know the details, but it sounds like you might be trying to do **integration testing** rather than **unit testing**. If you could isolate the dependency on `ServiceHost`, that would likely make your testing easier (and faster). So (for instance) you might test the following independently:

- Configuration reading class
- ServiceHost factory (possibly as an integration test)
- Engine class that takes an `IServiceHostFactory` and an `IConfiguration`

Tools that would help include isolation (mocking) frameworks and (optionally) IoC container frameworks. See:

- http://www.mockobjects.com/
- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx

Comment: I'm not trying to do integration testing. I do indeed need to do unit testing. I am thoroughly versed in TDD/BDD terms and practices (IoC, DI, Mocking, etc.), so the run of the mill kind of stuff like creating factories and using interfaces is not what I am in need of (its already done, except in the case of ServiceHost itself.) ServiceHost isn't a dependency that can be isolated, as it isn't properly mockable (as much of the .NET System namespaces.) I really need a way to run the unit tests serially.

Comment: @jrista - no slight on your skills was intended. I'm not a WCF developer, but would it be possible for the engine to return a wrapper around ServiceHost with an interface on the wrapper? Or perhaps a custom factory for ServiceHosts?

Comment: The hosting engine does not return any ServiceHosts. It actually does not return anything, it simply manages the creation, opening, and closing of ServiceHosts internally. I could wrap all the fundamental WCF types, but that is a LOT of work that I haven't really been authorized to do. Also, as it turned out, the problem is not caused by parallel execution, and will still happen during normal operation. I started another question here on SO about the problem, and hopefully I'll get an answer.

Comment: @TrueWill: BTW, I wasn't worried about you slighting my skills at all...I just didn't want to get a lot of run-of-the-mill answers that cover all the common stuff about unit testing. I needed a quick answer on a very specific problem. Sorry if I came off a bit gruff, wasn't my intention. I just have pretty limited time to get this thing working.

Answer (score 6):

you can Use **Playlist**

right click on the test method -> Add to playlist -> New playlist

then you can specify the execution order, the default is, as you add them to the play list but you can change the playlist file as you want

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use [Advanced Unit Testing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/autp3.aspx). [It allows you to define the sequence in which you run the test](http://www.marcclifton.com/Projects/AdvancedUnitTesting/tabid/102/Default.aspx). So you may have to create a new cs file to host those tests.

Here's how you can bend the test methods to work in the sequence you want.

```
[Test]
[Sequence(16)]
[Requires("POConstructor")]
[Requires("WorkOrderConstructor")]
public void ClosePO()
{
  po.Close();

  // one charge slip should be added to both work orders

  Assertion.Assert(wo1.ChargeSlipCount==1,
    "First work order: ChargeSlipCount not 1.");
  Assertion.Assert(wo2.ChargeSlipCount==1,
    "Second work order: ChargeSlipCount not 1.");
  ...
}
```

Do let me know whether it works.

Comment: Great article. I actually had it bookmarked on CP. Thanks for the link, but as it turned out, the problem seems to be much deeper, as test runners do not seem to run tests in parallel.

Comment: Wait, first you say you don't want the test to run in parallel, and then you say that the problem is that the test runners don't run tests in parallel... so which is which?

Comment: The link you provided no longer works. And is this something you can do with xunit?

Answer (score 3):

None of the suggested answers so far worked for me. I have a dotnet core app with XUnit 2.4.1. 
I achieved the desired behavior with a workaround by putting a lock in each unit test instead. In my case, I didn't care about running order, just that tests were sequential.

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Fact]
    void Test1()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            //Test Code
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    void Test2()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            //Test Code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've added the attribute **[Collection("Sequential")]** in a base class:

```
    namespace IntegrationTests
    {
      [Collection("Sequential")]
      public class SequentialTest : IDisposable
      ...


      public class TestClass1 : SequentialTest
      {
      ...
      }

      public class TestClass2 : SequentialTest
      {
      ...
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, in .Net Core Console application, when I wanted to run test methods ( not classes ) synchronously, the only solution which worked was this described in this blog:
[xUnit: Control the Test Execution Order](https://hamidmosalla.com/2018/08/16/xunit-control-the-test-execution-order/)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the correct solution for executing unit tests serially.**
Xunit provides a CollectionBehaviorAttribute class to handle the executing behavior of unit tests. This can help prevent race conditions, shared resource conflicts, and other issues that may arise when running tests concurrently.

```
using Xunit;
using Moq;    
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
namespace UnitTests
{ 
    public class UnitTest
    {
    }
}
```