# Execute test sequentially with Xunit in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, sequential

I want to run my tests sequentially as they change the same database and may affect one another. I have tried many solutions on the internet but none of them works for me. These solutions are described in the link "[Execute unit tests serially (rather than in parallel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408175/execute-unit-tests-serially-rather-than-in-parallel)".
I am kind of stuck now. Could anyone have some idea on this issue?

Answer (score 7):

From the docs:

> By default, each test class is a unique test collection.
>   Tests within the same test class will not run in parallel against each other.

For tests from different classes

> If we need to indicate that multiple test classes should not be run in
>   parallel against one another, then we place them into the same test
>   collection.
>   This is simply a matter of decorating each test class with
>   an attribute that places them into the same uniquely named test
>   collection

```
[Collection("Database tests")]
public class DeleteTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void RemovesItemFromDatabase()
    {
        // test
    }
}

[Collection("Database tests")]
public class InsertTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void InsertsItemToDatabase()
    {
        // test
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that approach. The decoration did not work for me. The tests inside the same class were still running in parallel.

Comment: @ThanhBinhNguyen, hmm, I doubt that this is a case. You probably need to share your code and explain how you are observing that tests in same class executed in parallel.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not easy to put the code here as my tests requires interacting with several docker programs. To observe the executions, I put debug messages before and after each test. What I saw was that sometimes a test has not finished before another test enters its execution. That how I observed the parallelism. Nevertheless, by the time I write to you this message, I have managed to force executing my tests in sequential manner (but not with the decoration described above). So far, I have not noticed any parallelism behaviors, so hopefully I did correctly.

Comment: What solution finally worked for you, Thanh Binh Nguyen ?

Comment: Indeed, despite this being also in the official documentation of xunit, it doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

To order xUnit tests with custom attributes, you first need an attribute to rely on. Define a PriorityAttribute as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PriorityAttribute : Attribute
{
    public PriorityAttribute(int priority)
    {
        Priority = priority;
    }

    public int Priority { get; private set; }
}
```

Next, consider the following PriorityOrderer implementation of he ITestCaseOrderer interface.

```
public class PriorityOrderer : ITestCaseOrderer
{
    public const string Name = "Namespace.PriorityOrderer";
    public const string Assembly = "Assembly name";

    private static string _priorityAttributeName = typeof(PriorityAttribute).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    private static string _priorityArgumentName = nameof(PriorityAttribute.Priority);

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> _defaultPriorities = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

    public IEnumerable<TTestCase> OrderTestCases<TTestCase>(IEnumerable<TTestCase> testCases) where TTestCase : ITestCase
    {
        var groupedTestCases = new Dictionary<int, List<ITestCase>>();
        var defaultPriorities = new Dictionary<Type, int>();

        foreach (var testCase in testCases)
        {
            var defaultPriority = DefaultPriorityForClass(testCase);
            var priority = PriorityForTest(testCase, defaultPriority);

            if (!groupedTestCases.ContainsKey(priority))
                groupedTestCases[priority] = new List<ITestCase>();

            groupedTestCases[priority].Add(testCase);
        }

        var orderedKeys = groupedTestCases.Keys.OrderBy(k => k);
        foreach (var list in orderedKeys.Select(priority => groupedTestCases[priority]))
        {
            list.Sort((x, y) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(x.TestMethod.Method.Name, y.TestMethod.Method.Name));
            foreach (TTestCase testCase in list)
                yield return testCase;
        }
    }

    private int PriorityForTest(ITestCase testCase, int defaultPriority)
    {
        var priorityAttribute = testCase.TestMethod.Method.GetCustomAttributes(_priorityAttributeName).SingleOrDefault();
        return priorityAttribute?.GetNamedArgument<int>(_priorityArgumentName) ?? defaultPriority;
    }

    private int DefaultPriorityForClass(ITestCase testCase)
    {
        var testClass = testCase.TestMethod.TestClass.Class;
        if (!_defaultPriorities.TryGetValue(testClass.Name, out var result))
        {
            var defaultAttribute = testClass.GetCustomAttributes(_defaultPriorityAttributeName).SingleOrDefault();
            result = defaultAttribute?.GetNamedArgument<int>(_priorityArgumentName) ?? int.MaxValue;
            _defaultPriorities[testClass.Name] = result;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Add the following attribute to classes for which you want tests run in order:

```
[TestCaseOrderer(PriorityOrderer.Name, PriorityOrderer.Assembly)]
public abstract class TestsBase
{
    private FieldInfo _counterField;

    public TestsBase()
    {
        _counterField = this.GetType().GetField("_counter", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        if (GetCounter() == null)
        {
            var facts = this.GetType().GetMethods()
                .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<FactAttribute>() != null);
            SetCounter(new bool[facts.Count()]);
        }
    }

    private bool[] GetCounter() => _counterField.GetValue(this) as bool[];

    private void SetCounter(bool[] value) => _counterField.SetValue(this, value);

    protected void VerifyAndFlip(int testNumber)
    {
        var counter = GetCounter();
        counter.Take(testNumber).Should().AllBeEquivalentTo(true);
        counter.Skip(testNumber).Should().AllBeEquivalentTo(false);

        counter[testNumber] = true;
        SetCounter(counter);
    }
}
```

Then decorate your test methods with the `Priority` attribute.

```
    [Fact, Priority(1)]
    public async Task Fact1_CorrectValue1_ReturnsTrue()
    {
       Assert.True(true);
    }

    [Fact, Priority(2)]
    public async Task Fact2_Value2_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        Assert.True(true);
    }
```